# Convert an object to list

Tags: android, list, object, casting, type-conversion

I didn't find efficient way. Can you help for it?

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> objMenus = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < menus.size(); i++)
{
     objMenus.add(menus.get(i));
}
tinydb.putObject("menus",objMenus);
```

`tinydb` supports Listobject and object. I store this value as object. 
Now, I want to convert this object to `List<List<Restaurant.Menu>>` again.

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Object> objMenus = new ArrayList<>();

objMenus.add(tinydb.getObject("menus", Object.class));

menus = ? convert objMenus
```

I tried several methods but they are not efficient. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't this be `ArrayList<Object> objMenus = tinydb.getListObject("menus",Object.class);` rather than `objMenus.add(tinydb.getObject("menus", Object.class));`?

Comment: Actually, There is no problem there, I can change it. The real problem is convertion.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will only work if `objMenus` contains *concrete* elements of `List<Restaurant.Menu>`.

Meaning, `objMenus` is of type `ArrayList<Object>` which is completely fine but each element of this `ArrayList` *must be referencing a `List<Restaurant.Menu>`*.

Using the Streams API:

```
List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = 
           objMenus.stream()
                   .map(e -> (List<Restaurant.Menu>) e)
                   .collect(toList());
```

Using the imperative approach:

```
List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object list : objMenus) {
     menus.add((List<Restaurant.Menu>)list);
}
```

Comment: First one has api level and support problem. Second has java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oz.ncclife.model.Restaurant$Menu problem.